# How to change script tag url automatically on build

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, r.js

I'm running Backbone with node using the following code in `index.html`

```
<script src="js/api/require.js"></script>
<script>require(['js/require-cfg'],function(){require(['main'])});</script>
```

`main.js` looks like this:

```
require(['app'], 
  function(App){
    App.initialize();
  }
);
```

In production, I compile the files using [r.js](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html) into `main-build.js` and redirect the link in the `index.html` file from **`main`** to **`main-build`**:

```
<script>require(['js/require-cfg'],function(){require(['main-build'])});</script>
```

Currently, if I want to deploy my code to production, I have to either manually change from `main` to `main-build` in `index.html`, or keep the link as `main-build` but change the contents of `main-build.js` to the same as `main.js` when I run a local or test environment, then switch back when deploying to production.

Is there a better (automatic) way of having the code use the compiled `main-build.js` when in production, and the content of `main.js` when in local or test environment?

eg: using node environment variables to either change the links in `index.html` (not sure how to change html!) or change the content of `main-build.js` but the content gets overwritten everytime r.js is run to compile for production

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally use [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) to process the `index.html` file with [gulp-html-replace](https://github.com/VFK/gulp-html-replace).

In development, you put the tags you need.

```html
<script src="js/api/require.js"></script>
<!-- build:js -->
<script>require(['js/require-cfg'],function(){require(['main'])});</script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

To make a build for production, create a gulp task which uses the *gulp-html-replace* plugin :

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    htmlreplace = require('gulp-html-replace');

gulp.task('build', function() {

    return gulp.src("index.html")
        .pipe(htmlreplace({
            js: {
                src: [['main-build']],
                tpl: '<script>require(["js/require-cfg"],function(){require(["%s"])});</script>'
            },
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("build/index.html"));
});
```

---

If you go the Gulp route, you could make all the build process through it. For example, here's a simple r.js task:

```
var rjs = require('requirejs');

gulp.task('optimize', function(done) {
    rjs.optimize({
        name: "main",
        out: "build/js/main.min.js",
        /* ...other options */
    }, function(buildResponse) {
        done();
    }, done);
});
```